# iOS swift move elements after some hidden

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, hidden

I have some question about moving elements in ScrollView, let say i have some form from few elements and button in the bottom on screen.
This view is scrolling and now i have some problems when i need to hidden some elements on this form, elements witch will goes after that stay as is, and as a result i have some blank space on form where places some hidden elements.
I think what is elements have Top space to options if i hidden some of them all others will move up after that but it's not.
I can not find some way how make auto up this elements what some elements was hidden.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: Yes i am using auto layout

Comment: Then create height constrain outlet for each view you want to hide and instead hiding view set constrain constant value to 0